# Access violation writing location on creation of new array

Tags: c++

I am working on a homework assignment and the instructor for my class does not allow us to ask questions. He demands that we try to figure it out all on our own but I have been trying to get this to work for the past week now and it is throwing the same error and I have no clue why. I have done some google searches and browsed SO for anyone who has a similar error and couldn't find a solution.

It works fine until after it creates the new array and user input is entered to start filling the new array, then it throws :

> First-chance exception at 0x000B517B in 6b.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation writing location 0x00008147.
>   The program '[4112] 6b.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int* read_data(int& size){
    size++;
    return &size;   
}

void main(){
    int size = 0; // size is 0 to start
    int max = 10; // set max to 10 to start
    float user; //user imputed float number

    cout << "Start entering your numbers.\n Be sure to hit RETURN between each one.\nWhen you are finished, hit 'Q'\n";

    float *a = new float [max]; //set first array that can be deleted and replaced

    do {
        //if the array is full, make a new one and replace.
        if(size == max){
            max = max *2; //double max number
            float *b = new float [max]; //create temporary array b

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                b[i] = a[i]; //copy old array to temporary
            }
            delete[] a; //remove old a array.
            float *a = new float [max]; //create new a array with the new max, same name for the loop.

            //copy new a array to resume filling
            for(int i = 0; i< size; i++){
                a[i] = b[i];
            }

            delete[] b; //remove temporary array to free memory.
        }

        cin >> user; // user inputs the number
        a[size] = user; //user input
        read_data(size); //increase size by one.
    }while (!cin.fail());

    size--; //remove one for the entering of Q otherwise it throws off the count.

    if (cin.fail()){
        cout << "\n\nYou have finished inputting.\n You have imputed " << size << " numbers. \nThe inputed numbers are as follows:\n";
        for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
            cout << a[i];

            if (i == size -1){
                cout << "\n\n";
            }
            else {
                cout << ", ";
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    system("pause"); 
}
```

The instructor wants the comments on basically every line which is why there is so many.

If anyone could help me with this it would be wonderful.

Comment: something wrong with indentation,

Comment: Stackoverflow is not the place for debuggin your homeworks, I would not downvote questions but it is likely there will be people downvoting your question because not appropiate. You should first of all identify the failing line of code (I already did that, but it will not benefit you gettin the "free" bug fix), try to use `cerr<<"Code executed till here -- 001"` to find last correct piece of code (use `cerr` instead of `cout`) because `cerr` will always print (sometimes `cout` will not print the message if program crash).. It would be better a debugger, but you are on terminal aren't you?

Comment: Using SO was a last resort. I am using Visual Studio 2012. I'll keep the cerr in mind for next time, thank you for letting me know about it, the instructor told us nothing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 delete[] a; //remove old a array.
```

This deletes the `a` array that you declared in the outer scope of your `main()` function, up top.

Next line:

```
 float *a = new float [max];
```

This creates a new variable named `a` in the inner scope. Going forward, what you think is happening to your original `a`, that was declared at the beginning of your `main()` is really being done to this other `a`. The original `a` is "hidden", and, as such, when this scope ends, the new array that you allocated is leaked, and your original `a` array is now pointing to unallocated memory.

Hillarity ensues.

> "The more you overthink the plumbing, the easier it is to stop up the
>   drain" - Scotty, Star Trek III.

After you allocated the new `b` array, and copied the contents of `a` to it, all you really needed to do was:

```
 a=b;
```

You don't need to allocate another `a` array, and copy it back from `b`, then delete `b`. That accomplishes absolutely nothing, and doing that you inadvertently ended up making a fairly evil mistake...

Comment: the new a is supposed to replace the first a that was created outside of the loop, that was by design. Once the first a array is filled it is copied to temp b array so that the larger a array can be created and re-filled. It is part of the assignment to make a pseudo-infinite array that can be filled continuously.

Comment: Although, as I said, this is a waste of time, if you feel like you need to copy the same array twice, instead of once, don't declare it again. Instead of `float *a = new float [max];` the second time, just `a = new float [max];`. But you'll probably get marked down, I'm fairly certain that you only needed to allocate and copy the array just once.

Comment: Ah! sorry, I responded before you edited. The book we are working on has weird things like that in it and it is what the instructor is expecting since it is an introductory coarse. Removing the float * worked. Thank you VERY much for the help. The instructor was not very clear on how to use dynamic allocation arrays.